# Humans unearthing the ruins of current civilization; discover a football pitch and think it’s a form of sun worship

Tags: story-identification

I read this book a long time ago and have been trying find it again.  For the life of me I cannot remember the title.  It involves a future generation of humans unearthing the ruins of our current/modern civilization.  I remember a section where a football field is discovered and they interpret it as a form of sun worship which involved people being sacrificed on the goal posts.

Comment: Could it be one of the works reviewed in [this article](http://www.locusmag.com/Perspectives/2009/08/gary-westfahl-addled-archaeology-of.html)?

Comment: Could be this but these are aliens and not humans http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/which-short-story-was-about-aliens-thinking-soccer-was-a-form-of-worship

Comment: I'll avoid linking to the TV Tropes "Future Imperfect" entry, namely because I read through and there's no mention of football. On a side note, search for "football and sun worship" on Google and you'll find a number of people hold that belief today.

Comment: Could it have been *Motel of the Mysteries* written by David Macaulay? It's an old book (published 1979) depicting a 41st century archaeologist unearthing a motel from 1985.

Comment: Could this be one of the "Nacirema" joke papers? (See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nacirema) There was a collection of them published in 1975 called _The Nacirema: Readings on American Culture_ that might be the collection of which you're thinking.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this book: "Motel of Mysteries" [http://www.amazon.com/Motel-Mysteries-David-Macaulay/dp/0395284252](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0395284252)

> It is the year 4022; all of the ancient country of Usa has been buried under many feet of detritus from a catastrophe that occurred back in 1985. Imagine, then, the excitement that Howard Carson, an amateur archeologist at best, experienced when in crossing the perimeter of an abandoned excavation site he felt the ground give way beneath him and found himself at the bottom of a shaft, which, judging from the DO NOT DISTURB sign hanging from an archaic doorknob, was clearly the entrance to a still-sealed burial chamber. Carson's incredible discoveries, including the remains of two bodies, one of then on a ceremonial bed facing an altar that appeared to be a means of communicating with the Gods and the other lying in a porcelain sarcophagus in the Inner Chamber, permitted him to piece together the whole fabric of that extraordinary civilization.

Comment: Please add an explanation why you think this is the answer.